# What is the Fourier transform of $1$?

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory

For sure, $g(x)=1$ has no fourier transform, but it has a Fourier transform in distribution sense. We have for $\varphi \in \mathcal C_0^\infty (\mathbb R)$, $$\left<\hat 1,\varphi \right>:=\left<1,\hat \varphi \right>=\int_{\mathbb R}\hat \varphi (x)dx=\int_{\mathbb R}\hat \varphi (x)e^{2i\pi0x}dx=\varphi (0)=\left<\delta ,\varphi \right>.$$
Do at the end $\hat 1=\delta $. Could someone explain what it mean ? Because in somehow, $\hat 1$ doesn't make sense strongly, but in distribution it is $\delta $, and I'm not sure how to interpret this. Could someone help to try to understand ?

Comment: You seem to agree with the logical implications of the definition. So if you're not happy, I suppose you're not satisfied with the definition of a distributional fourier transform?

Comment: Please restate the question, so that only defined objects are used. If you **use** $\hat 1$ and its definition, it is hard to see where is the point in the question. In the given situation it is clear from the question that $\hat 1$ is a distribution. And a distribution is determined by the duality pairing. So having the equality $\langle\hat 1, \phi\rangle=\langle \delta,\phi\rangle$ for every test function $\phi$, we have also $\hat 1=\delta$. Where is the logical "hole" in the discussion?!

Answer (score 0):

$g$ is a locally integrable function, hence a tempered distribution. Fourier transform of a tempered distribution $u$ is defined by $\hat {u} (\phi)=u(\hat {\phi})$.

Comment: Does it really answer to my question ? I know that $\left<\hat 1, \varphi \right>=\left<1,\hat \varphi \right>$...

Comment: Yes, it answers your question, to thhe extent an answer is possible. You asked what  tte equation $\hat 1=\delta$  means. What it means is (by definition) exactly the string of equalities displayed in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The distribution $u = 1$ is the linear map on test functions $\left<u,\phi\right> = \int_\Bbb{R} \phi(x)dx$ its Fourier transform $\hat{u}$ is the linear map on test functions such that $\left<\hat{u},\phi\right>=\left<u,\hat{\phi}\right>$.

ie. $$\left<\hat{u},\phi\right> = \int_\Bbb{R} \hat{\phi}(x)dx= \phi(0) = \left<\delta,\phi\right>$$

> So $\hat{u}$ and $\delta$ are the same linear map on test functions, they are the same distribution.

If we define those things like that it is because from the beginning we are considering $u$ as the limit of a sequence of (test) functions $u_n$, sequence which maybe doesn't converge to a function but whose corresponding sequence of linear map $\left<u_n,.\right>$ on test functions converges.

Comment: So you mean that there is a sequence $(u_n)$ of test function s.t. $u_n\to u$ ? If yes how do you know that ? (I mean if $u$ is locally integrable). Also, the convergence hold in which sense ?